# Brief book on calculus to read before studying the analysis

Tags: calculus, textbooks, mathematical-analysis, self-learning, reference-books

I am going to start studying the analysis texts (Rudin-PMA, Apostol-MA, Pugh-RMA) on the first week of August.  I have a good proof skills through working on Artin's Algebra and Hoffman/Kunze's Linear Algebra, but I unfortunately only took computational 1-variable calculus (Lang's A First Course in Calculus), and I did not take multivariable calculus, which I might take concurrently with Analysis I and Theoretical Linear Algebra on the upcoming Fall.

I am looking for a brief text which explains the key ideas from both 1-variable and multivariable calculus, one I can read and jump directly into the analysis texts.  Could you recommend one?

Also will my lack of multivariable calculus be a problem when I tackle those analysis texts?  I seem to understand at least the beginning chapters.

Comment: [**Calculus of Several Variables**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0063561859) by Casper Goffman is old (1966), but might be a good fit for what you want. I don't know how easily available it is to buy (or find on the internet), but I do know that it's very common in U.S. college/university libraries.

Answer (score 4):

I first learned calculus from the predecessor of the current college outline series Calculus, which you can get from Amazon for 59 cents, free shipping if you sign up for a trial 6 month trial of "Amazon Student."

[http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Harcourt-Jovanovich-College-Outline/dp/0156015560/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438026539&sr=8-1&keywords=college+outline+series+calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0156015560)

A second edition of my analysis book will be out in September.  Among other things it adds a discussion of visualizing in 4D.

Best, Charles Pugh

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, Professor Pugh.  Your textbook "Real Mathematical Analysis" is a very outstanding analysis text, and it beats Rudin and Apostol from the exposition to the quality of problem sets.  However, should I be familiarized myself with the multivariable calculus first before studying your later chapters on multivariable analysis?  If so, is Serge Lang's Calculus of Several Variables enough for the background?

Comment: I had forgotten about Lang's book when I mentioned Goffman's book in my earlier comment (under your question). I think Lang's book would be great for you, and in fact I've used it myself at times when I needed to review certain topics in elementary multivariable calculus. See my comments about Lang's book in this [21 January 2011 Math Forum archived post.](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7365390) However, I don't think you'll need any multivariable calculus for Pugh's book until you get to the chapter on multivariable calculus, which is more than halfway through his book.